# Iterate table row and cell and change specific styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through each row to check marks for that particular person and comparing it with Score Column Value for that person only. If the **

> marks > score, the cell background color will be green, else it will
>   turn red.

** I am able to color the cells but it is only considering score value of 1st row only. I am trying to understand what i am missing here?

```js
$('#'+'marksbody').find('tr>td').each(function(i, el) {

    var scoreValue1=  $('#'+'marksbody'+' tr td:nth-child(7) > label[id^="score"]')[0].innerHTML.split("%")[0].trim();
  
    var scoreValue=(scoreValue1 == null || scoreValue1 == '') ? 0 : Number(scoreValue1);
    console.log("Score Value : " + scoreValue)
    if(isNaN(Number($(this).text().split("%")[0].trim())) ==false && Number($(this).text().split("%")[0].trim())>=Number(scoreValue)){
      $(this).css({'background-color':'lightgreen'});
    }
    else  if(isNaN(Number($(this).text().split("%")[0].trim())) ==false && Number($(this).text().split("%")[0].trim())<Number(scoreValue)){
      $(this).css({'background-color':'red'});
    }
  });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
       <th>MArks2</th>
       <th>Mark3s</th>
      <th>Marks4</th>
       <th>MArks5</th>
       <th>MArks6</th>
       <th>score</th>
       <th>Avg</th>
       <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="marksbody">
    <tr>
      <td>Rock</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>25</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td>40</td>
       <td>50</td>
      <td><label id="score1">0</label></td>
       <td>80</td>
       <td>90</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Alex</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>25</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td>40</td>
       <td>50</td>
       <td id="score2">40</td>
       <td>80</td>
       <td>90</td>
    </tr>
    
     <tr>
      <td>Chen</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>25</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td>40</td>
       <td>50</td>
       <td id="score3">50%</td>
       <td>80</td>
       <td>90</td>
    </tr>
      
      <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
       <td>20</td>
       <td>25</td>
       <td>28</td>
       <td>40</td>
       <td>50</td>
       <td id="score4">60</td>
       <td>80</td>
       <td>90</td>
    </tr>
      
       <tr>
  <td>Zen</td>
   <td>0.49</td>
   <td>1.2</td>
   <td>0.8</td>
   <td>0.6</td>
   <td>1.4</td>
   <td id="score5">1.05</td>
   <td>80</td>
   <td>90</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('#'+'marksbody'+' tr td:nth-child(7)` always selects the 7th TD of table. It has no reference to `each` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your snippet so that it iterates over **row**s then over individual **cell**s in that row.

By referencing a static element of each row (`$(row).find("td")[6]` (this is a 0 based index, so **[6]** is the seventh column) the function always compares the actual cell's value to the **score**.

`$(row).find("td")[6]` returns a DOM element - if you want to use jQuery on this element, you have to wrap it again: `$($(row).find("td")[6])` (otherwise an error will be thrown).

```js
$("#marksbody > tr").each(function(i, row) {
  $(row).find("td").each(function(j, cell) {
    const cellValue = parseInt($(cell).text().trim(), 10)
    // creating a reference cell (score)
    // beware (!) you have to wrap the found element in $() again!
    const score = parseInt($($(row).find("td")[6]).text().trim(), 10)
    if (!isNaN(cellValue) && cellValue > score) {
      $(cell).css('background-color', 'lightgreen')
    } else if (!isNaN(cellValue)) {
      $(cell).css('background-color', 'red')
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>MArks2</th>
      <th>Mark3s</th>
      <th>Marks4</th>
      <th>MArks5</th>
      <th>MArks6</th>
      <th>score</th>
      <th>Avg</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="marksbody">
    <tr>
      <td>Rock</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td><label id="score1">0</label></td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alex</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td id="score2">40</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Chen</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td id="score3">50%</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td id="score4">60</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Zen</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td id="score5">70</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>90</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all Thank you for your answer. It is working great but when the table have decimal nos in cell it is ignoring decimal values due to parseInt. Any ideas, how we can resolve that?

Comment: I changed it to parseFloat. Seems, its working fine

Comment: :) Yep, that’s a solution